# How can I merge an image scanned in parts into one complete whole?

Tags: scanning

I have a large image I traced and cut into smaller images to scan (because I have a small scanner).

I need to manually merge the images back together but am only finding automated features that won't work for me because there is no overlap.

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Which software are you using and/or do you have available? Photoshop? Other? Wanting software recommendations?

Answer (score 12):

If you really want to do this manually, I think you could create an image large enough to hold the end-product, then paste the pieces in (probably each in their own layer) and align by hand.  When you're done sliding layers around, you could then merge back into a single layer.

Alternatively, you could re-scan with a little overlap across images and use something like [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/scans/en.shtml) to stitch them back together again.  This might end up being easier and more reliable in the long run.

Comment: yeah, I think you have to have some overlap or you'll end up with a seam. You may have to re-scan and assemble (for example) six source files instead of four, but the assembly will be worth the end product, I think. I've had to do the same thing and that's been my experience.

Answer (score 0):

This panorama tool:
http://www.ptgui.com/panotools.html

can artfully join the photos into a single panorama image. Probably it could help you with your question.

Comment: The OP mentions that there is no overlap, so automated pano tools will probably fail here.