# How to join separate scans of same object

Tags: gimp, scanning, photo-editing

Am scanning game maps using an A4 scanner, so typically they are more than one file.

Is there a semi-automatic or automatic way to join them properly?

For example, take two images that might overlap a bit on one side, and are possibly not exactly aligned, so need a slight rotation, and produce one image?

Ideally, I would be using GIMP, but if some other tool does it better then that is fine too.

**Edit**: [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87645/recombine-scanned-images-without-seam/87652) is similar, and I have actually done this in the past, with camera sw. I thought maybe there would be a simpler solution nowadays, and one not requiring MS windows.

Comment: Hi Tomas, Welcome to Graphic Design StackExchange. We hope you enjoy your stay and sharing with us. "Stitching" is the term used to join pieces of a panorama together seamlessly. That should make your search easier.

Comment: @Stan: ok, thanks. (Shouldn't there be a tag for stitching, then?)

Comment: That would increase the number of tags to include every menu item in all of the software we use. Thatsalottatags!!! It might not be practical. Suggest it in meta.

Comment: I don't know how well panorama stitching methods work with something like game maps, but that would be the first thing I'd try. There are standalone applications too, but since you asked about gimp, here's one plugin for it: http://stitchpanorama.sourceforge.net/ - There's also a list of other applications at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Hi, Tomas, I suggest you to give a look to [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/), which is a well-known panorama photo stitcher. There is a tutorial related to [stitching flat scanned images](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/scans/en.shtml).

Comment: See also https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/how-can-i-merge-an-image-scanned-in-parts-into-one-complete-whole